# Crontab run every 15 minutes except at 3AM?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

Is it possible to have a cronjob run every 15 minutes (over every hour etc..) except for at 3AM?

I have another special cronjob I want to run at 3AM, but I don't want the other one to run at the same time...

Comment: Easiest would be to let the crontab execute a script that checks if it's 3AM, and if so, just exits.

Comment: Ideally you should use some sort of lock system. Set a shared flag with one job, and check if that flag is set with the second job.

Comment: Two answers in comments?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

With one cron line, no. With three, yes:

```
# Every 15 minutes except for 3:00-3:59
*/15 0-2,4-23 * * * thejob
# 3:15, 3:30, 3:45
15-45/15 3 * * * thejob
# 3:00 dead
0 3 * * * otherjob
```

Comment: To date this is the most clear example I have found yet. While it would be possible in two lines after modifying richrosa's response, this one is much much easier to read. Thank you for sharing! +1

Comment: @bwright, the two lines you would write in light of @richrosa's answer would be equivalent to lines 2 and 4 in this answer. Also, IMO, `15,30,45` is more readable than `15-45/15`.

Answer (score 12):

I made my own solution, but I wanted to see what other people thought of!

I put this on the top of my desired script. I wanted it to not run at the half hour either so it doesn't do it on both.

On top of the script:

```
if [ $(date +%M) = 00 ] || [ $(date +%M) = 30 ]
then
exit
fi
```

The cron line:

```
*/15 * * * * ~/path/to/file
```

Hope anyone uses my solution too.

Comment: This is nice, but is has one issue. The logic is spread across 2 files: one being the cronjob and the other your actual command. Someone can easily fail to see both solutions and think there must be a cronjob collision.

Answer (score 2):

```
 0,15,30,45 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * * your cron job
```

Comment: That won't run at 3:15 am, 3:30 am, 3:45 am, so you need another line in the crontab for these hours.