# Cron expression for each 5 minutes except hours between 01:00 and 02:00?

Tags: cron

My need is clear in the title. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question may help with the the cron expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764150/crontab-run-every-15-minutes-except-at-3am

Comment: It would have been nice to see what you have tried already. Many don't like questions which don't show any initial effort to solve the problem.

Comment: this web may be can help you to test: https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try this :

```
0 0/5 0,2-23 * * ?
```

Comment: Thanks, then what about same but except between 01.00 and 01.30?

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think any CRON exception will meet your last need. Since you're using CRON exception within Spring, I guess that you'll have to implement a workaround by adding a conditional test in the beginning of the method you've annotated with @Scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this `0 0/5 0,2-23 * * ?`

Comment: Your trigger won't run between 2:00 and 3:00.

Comment: Because of the first right answer was given by KHY, I had to accept his answer. But I also flag useful yours. Thanks a lot.