# Quartz.NET - Run every hour except for 3am on Monday Mornings

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

What is the best way to tackle setting up a job to run every hour of every day except for Monday morning at 3am? My ideal goal is to have an alternate job run in that position.

I have my two classes setup to be the Jobs - UpdateJob and FullJob.
FullJob is the one that should only work once per week.

Comment: Have you tried [`CronTrigger`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html)?

Comment: I'm looking at it. I can figure out the first part. Just no idea how to exclude the 3am in the first Trigger.

Comment: Can you do 2 triggers? One would be "every hour on every day, except mondays" (`* * * * SUN,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT`), the other "every hour, except 3am, on mondays" (`* 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * MON`)

Comment: That could work and is a nice approach. Can you make that an official answer. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an older [cron-related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764150/crontab-run-every-15-minutes-except-at-3am), I received the idea to use two [`CronTrigger`s](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html) to accomplish this:

1. "every hour, on every day, except Mondays":

   ```
   * * * * SUN,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT
   ```
2. "every hour, except 3am, on Mondays":

   ```
   * 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * MON
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had slightly different requirements. However, I thought I'd leave this here for future readers.

Basically you can set advanced scheduling with a *CronTrigger* which takes a *CronExpression*.

[Lesson 6: CronTrigger](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html)

> CronTriggers are often more useful than SimpleTrigger, if you need a
> job-firing schedule that recurs based on calendar-like notions, rather
> than on the exactly specified intervals of SimpleTrigger.
>
> With CronTrigger, you can specify firing-schedules such as “every
> Friday at noon”, or “every weekday and 9:30 am”, or even “every 5
> minutes between 9:00 am and 10:00 am on every Monday, Wednesday and
> Friday”.
>
> Even so, like SimpleTrigger, CronTrigger has a startTime which
> specifies when the schedule is in force, and an (optional) endTime
> that specifies when the schedule should be discontinued.

**Cron Expressions**

> Cron-Expressions are used to configure instances of CronTrigger.
> Cron-Expressions are strings that are actually made up of seven
> sub-expressions, that describe individual details of the schedule.
> These sub-expression are separated with white-space, and represent:
>
> - Seconds
> - Minutes
> - Hours
> - Day-of-Month
> - Month
> - Day-of-Week
> - Year (optional field)
>
> An example of a complete cron-expression is the string
> “0 0 12 ? * WED” - which means “every Wednesday at 12:00 pm”.

**Example Implementation**

There are many ways to set and scaffold Quartz.Net, and the code I use may vary a lot to other implementations, however someone might find this useful.

```
public static void SetSchedule<T>(this IScheduler source, TimeSpan minWaitSeconds, string cron)
   where T : IJob
{
   var jobName = typeof(T).Name;

   var triggerKey = new TriggerKey($"{jobName} Trigger");

   DateTimeOffset minNextTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(2) + minWaitSeconds;

   var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                               .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                               .StartAt(minNextTime)
                               .WithCronSchedule(cron)
                               .Build();
       
   var jobKey = new JobKey(jobName);

   var job = JobBuilder.Create<T>()
                       .WithIdentity(jobKey)
                       .Build();

   source.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var startAt = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5);
var schedule = "0/5 * 8-16 ? * MON-FRI"

scheduler.SetSchedule<WarehousePickupNotificationJob>(startAt, schedule);
```

***Note** : My use case was that I needed a Task to run every 5 seconds, between certain hours, on week days*.

**Breakdown**

```
"0/5 * 8-17 ? * MON-FRI"
```

- `0/5`
- **Seconds** (The `/` character can be used to specify increments to values), which reads as run every 5 seconds
- `*`
- **Minutes** (`*` denotes all), which reads all minutes
- `8-16`
- **Hours** (`-` denotes to), which reads from "8am to 5pm" Not that the end number is inclusive
- `?`
- **Day-of-Month** (The `?` character is allowed for the day-of-month and day-of-week fields. It is used to specify "no specific value")
- `*`
- **Month field** (`*` denotes all), which reads all months
- `MON-FRI`
- **Day-of-Week** (`-` denotes to), which reads all week days