# Offset cron job for only one instance?

Tags: linux, perl, cron

I have a script that updates status for quite a few "things".  It has 5 different sub routines.  4 of the subroutines need to run every 5 minutes, and 1 of them only needs to run once at 12:05 AM.  The problem is, when the script executes at 12:05, it takes approximately 8 minutes to complete.  This causes the next iteration to begin at 12:10 before the previous one completed.  Resources assigned to the second iteration cause the first to run slower, pushing its completion past the 10 minute mark, allowing for a third iteration to begin.  As you can imagine, the various versions layering on each other will eventually overwhelm the machine and cause a crash.

The simple solution would be to split the file into two and create separate cron jobs, and I will certainly do that if there's no other option.  However, I would prefer to keep all of the status subs in the same file if possible, so as to simplify installation and maintenance (will be installed and used on quite a few machines).

I'm hoping that there is an offset cron entry that will run the script at 12:05 AM every morning, wait 10 minutes before running it again, and then run it every 5 minutes after that.  Essentially:

12:05, 12:15, 12:20, 12:25, 12:30, etc

The script knows that it was executed once already, and will not run the 5th sub for the rest of the day, making the 5 minute gap acceptable.

Please let me know if that all made sense.  Happy to go into more detail if needed.  Thank you in advance for any information you can provide.  Much appreciated.

Comment: How about allowing the long-running subroutine to set a lockfile?  If the next iteration finds the lockfile still there (and a lock held on the file), it simply returns without executing its payload.  Another option would be to set a cron to run at 12:05 with one set of command-line args, and the another one at 12:10 with another set of command-line args that cause the long-running sub to be skipped.

Comment: You can skip a cron job, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764150/crontab-run-every-15-minutes-except-at-3am). I am not completely sure what exactly you need, but it seems to be a duplicate of this post. On the same page there is another option, to have the script itself abort a run at a given time (or, rather, perhaps more safely within an interval).

Comment: I did mark it as a duplicate of what I mentioned above.  Please let me know if I missed something in your question that the linked asnwer(s) don't deal with.

Comment: While my question may truly be a duplicate, I'm not sure I agree that it is duplicated by that particular link.  The solution in that link is a multiple-line entry, which effectively creates the same "less-than-simplified" scenario as splitting the script into two files.  I understand that there may not be a single-line solution, in which case the answer is "No, you can't do that,", as opposed to it being a duplicate of a solution that doesn't stick to the simplified requirements.

Comment: That said, I like DavidO's solution of creating a lockfile.  Oddly, this is exactly how I keep the script from executing the 5th sub routine throughout the rest of the day, but it never occurred to me to use it the opposite way for the initial execution.  I guess that's the danger of staying up too late trying to solve a problem.  Thanks DavidO, much appreciated!